# Как удалить массив из многомерного массива

Tags: массивы, php

Есть массив:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "13"
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "тег1dfed"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "14"
    ["name"]=>
    string(2) "11"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "15"
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "dwdw"
  }
}
```

Как удалить его? пробовал вот так:

```
foreach ($data_temp as $key) {
  unset($data_temp[$key]);
}
```

Сервер говорит ошибку:

> Illegal offset type in unset in

Comment: Странный вопрос, если честно. Если вы хотите удалить переменную, то достаточно сделать

    unset($data_temp);

Если же вы хотите удалить данные из переменной и сделать массив пустым, то проще ничего не придумаешь, чем

    $data_temp = array();

Это будет корректно, и если на вложенные объекты никто нигде больше не ссылается (т.е. вложенные массивы не присвоены никаким переменным), то память будет очищена [сборщиком мусора][1].

Вам **нет необходимости** перед удалением **очищать вложенные массивы**!

  [1]: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.gc.php

Comment: Попробуйте

foreach ($data_temp as &$key) {
  unset($key);
}

Хотя выше (т.е. ниже) Вам дали наводку на причины ошибки удаления

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($data_temp as $key => $list) { 
    unset($data_temp[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В Вашем случае переменная $key будет содержать ключевое слово Array. Это и вызывает ошибку.

Как вариант, если использовать цикл, можно через for:

```
    for($i = 0, $c = count($data_temp); $i < $c; $i++) {
        unset($data_temp[$i]);
    }
```

Comment: Ваше решение будет работать только с последовательным массивом, но не сработает ни в случае ассоциативного массива, ни в случае, если будет пропущен какой-то индекс. Например, если я сначала выполню

    unset($data_temp[1])

а затем запущу ваш код, то получу предупреждение illegal offset